# Select text using keyboard in linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

It is common to not use the mouse at all in a terminal, but it is not easy to find how to select text in a terminal just with the keyboard.

Once selected <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> can be used to copy and paste, but how to select text?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210768/how-do-i-select-text-from-terminal-by-using-keyboard-only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found this on net..

1. Open screen: screen
2. Run your program, producing output you want copied
3. Enter copy mode: ^A [
4. Move your cursor to the start point
5. Hit enter
6. Move your cursor to the end point
7. Hit enter
8. Paste: ^A ]

would that do ?

Answer (score 4):

Highlighting with the mouse. *runs*

Comment: No need to run, I fixed that for you :)